# Is there a name for these permutations?

Tags: graph-isomorphism

Given adjacency matrix $A$ of a graph is there a name for permutations $P$ such that $A=PAP'$?

Is this an automrphic permutation?

Comment: Yes, you can call it a graph isomorphism (as the permutation takes vertices to vertices in such a way that edges go to edges in 1-to-1 fashion) or a graph automorphism.  Collectively all such permutations (of the vertices) would form a group, called the automorphism group of the particular graph.

Comment: I assume that by $P'$ you mean the transpose of $P$, which is also the inverse of $P$.